# Find PID number from Torch/ Tensorflow DEvice

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, pid, torch

I'm running three PyTorch models from three different Jupyter Notebooks (let's call them JN1, JN2, and JN3) (python 3.6). All the models run on the same GPU (Titan Xp) which is a shared resource and is hosted on a different server.

I am finished with one of the models/notebooks (JN1) and would like to close the PID process corresponding to this model alone. nvidia-smi gives me a list of PID processes and their numbers - however, I'm not sure which is the PID number corresponding to JN1.

Is there a way that I can find the PID number of this model directly from the notebook or the torch model?

Comment: Have you tried this :

import os
print(os.getpid())

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer, is there  a way to close the pid process from the notebook directly as well?

Comment: Can you please try this:  import signal os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer- this works but it kills the kernel and then restarts it. When I run sudo kill-9 pid in the shell, our system asks for a password - which might be safer. But this is really helpful!

Comment: So what did you use to kill the process safely ?

Comment: I wasn't able to kill it safely. I ended up just closing the kernel.

Comment: Can you try this: import os
os.system("kill -9 {0}".format(pid))

Comment: Same thing- the kernel just died.

Comment: How many pids are being returned by this command : print(os.getpid())

Comment: Right now, there is just one. But same response. Just killed the notebook